# How to compile a C-File that calls a Python-Method on Windows 10 with Python.h and MinGW

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, compilation

I needed to compile a C-Programm that uses the `Python.h` to call a Python-Method from an existing Python-File.

And all that on a Windows 10 machine with `MinGW`.

As I could not find a straight-up answer on what compile command I need, I will now post what works for me in the hope it helps others too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The command that worked for me is as follows:**

```
gcc -o nameOfexe nameOfCFile.c -I PathToPython\include -L PathToPython\libs  -lpythonXX
```

---

**Explanation:**

- *nameOfexe*:
  the name you want for your .exe, so to speak the result of the command
- *nameOfCFile.c* :
  the C-File you want to compile and holds the call to the Python-Method
- *PathToPython\include*:
  the path to your python\include folder, example: C:\Python_3_9_0\include
- *PathToPython\libs*:
  the path to your python\libs folder, example: C:\Python_3_9_0\libs
- *-lpythonXX*:
  that specifies what lib to compile for python to work,
  *XX* = your version: python3.9.0 --> -lpython39

Both the C-File and the Python-File are in the same Folder I run the command in.